# ImmutableJS - filtering nested Map{List(Map{...})}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, immutability, immutable.js

Given the following data structure.

```js
let hall = Map({
  tables: Map({
    t1: Map({
      playlist: List(
        Map({
          songid: 'target'
        })
      )
    }),
    t2: Map({
      playlist: List(
        Map({
          songid: 'not me'
        })
      )
    })
  })
});
```

How do I iterate over each table (t1, t2, ...) and remove the item in the list with `songid === 'target'` so that I end up with:

```js
let expected_hall = Map({
  tables: Map({
    t1: Map({
      playlist: List()
    }),
    t2: Map({
      playlist: List(
        Map({
          songid: 'not me'
        })
      )
    })
  })
});
```

Tried the following to no avail:

```js
let res = hall;
hall.get('tables').entrySeq().forEach(e => {
  res = res.updateIn(['tables', e[0], 'playlist'], list => list.filter(songinfo => songinfo.songid === 'target'));
});

// or using  hall.get('tables').map(...)
```

Appreciate for all the help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let hall = Map({
  tables: Map({
    t1: Map({
      playlist: List.of(
        Map({
          songid: 'target'
        })
      )
    }),
    t2: Map({
      playlist: List.of(
        Map({
          songid: 'not me'
        })
      )
    })
  })
});
```

The way you've used List, it should be List.of(...) or List([])

I would do it like this:

```js
const hall2 = hall.update("tables", tables => (
  tables.map(table => (
    table.update("playlist", playlist => playlist.filter(p => p.get("songid")!=="not me"))
  ))
));
```

You update the tables property, iterate over each table, update the playlist property and filter the playlist by each item on not being "not me"

Answer (score -1):

Docs of [List#filter](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/filter)

> Returns a new List with only the values for which the predicate function returns true.

So here we have to return which list whom `songid` **IS NOT** `target`

```html
let res = hall;
hall.get('tables').keySeq().forEach(e => {
  res = res.updateIn(['tables', e, 'playlist'], list => list.filter(info => info.get("songid") !== "target"));
});
```